# What's the purpose of this static struct?

Tags: c++, c, struct

I came across the code below and I'm a little confused as to its purpose.

```
struct bob{
    int myNum;
    struct bob * next;
};

static struct bob_stuff{
    int theNum;
    struct bob *lists;
} bob;
```

I know the second struct is static and being intialized as a bob struct, but why would you do that? But I'm not really sure why'd you have 2 structs.

Comment: The second struct is not of type `struct bob`, it is of type `struct bob_stuff`. There's a very important distinction. While the members of the structs are equivalent, the two structs are not assignable to each other.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `static` only applies to the variable `bob`, not the `struct bob_stuff`.

Comment: Static member only can be accessed from their file and from other file you can not access them, here you can not access bob from other files but you have access to struct bob_stuff and struct bob.

Comment: That is just a bad idea, declarations and definitions should be separated. The `static` there applies as everyone said to the instance `bob` of type `struct bob_stuff`. Where do you get such examples from? they are really bad examples.

Comment: So the static structs bob_stuff actually contains a list of bob structs that are static, but the int myNum is not static?  What is the deal with the "bob" at the end of the declaration of the struct bob_stuff?

Comment: It's bad practice to use the same name for both a type and a variable, especially in the same context.

Comment: I think bob variable is static, not struct bob_stuff and lists or theNum ...

Comment: In the `static` case, the last `bob` is the (only) variable being declared.  The `static` therefore applies to `bob`, and not to anything else.  Everything between `static` and (the last) `bob` is the type of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like "module" (or "class", if you will) state for maintaining a bunch of singly-linked lists of integers.

Of course the naming is terrible, it should be e.g.

```
struct list_node {
  int myNum;
  struct list_node *next;
};

static struct {
  int theNum;
  struct list_node *lists;
} listState;
```

Note that the name ("struct tag") `bob_stuff` is pointless and confusing, and should probably be removed. If you want a `static`, thus local, variable of `struct` type, chances are the tag won't be useful anyway.

Comment: Thanks that clears it up.  Would the myNum be static or not? My guess is not because since part of the list_node struct that is not static, even though is is part of a list contained in the listState variable.

Comment: Nothing about `struct list_node` "is `static`", that's just a type being declared. The fact that `listState`, which is a static variable, contains a pointer to values of that type doesn't change the type declaration itself.

Answer (score 3):

I think that it is the names of the structures that confuse you.

It is a definition of a single linked list.

The first structure

```
struct bob{
    int myNum;
    struct bob * next;
};
```

defines a node of the list. That it would be more clear I will rewrite it with different names

```
struct Node{
    int value;
    struct Node * next;
};
```

The second structure simply defines a head of the list and the number of nodes in the list (as I thik)

```
static struct bob_stuff{
    int theNum;
    struct bob *lists;
} bob;
```

So it can be rewritten like

```
static struct SingleLinkedList{
    int nodes_count;
    struct Node *head;
} list;
```

This abstract list is used as a container for some Bob stuff.:)